# Windows 7 administrator can't see some files? Or sees different files?

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

As a normal user, I'd edited some files that ordinarily ordinary users wouldn't be editing (specifically, Intellij IDEA `.vmoptions` files, in `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\Intellij IDEA 10.5.2\bin`), without the effects I was hoping for, and I saw some noise elsewhere on the web about [administrators and normal users seeing different versions of these files](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5251011;jsessionid=E36AB39207680DF3A56BC94E9A839B26) (???!), so I decided to try to edit them as administrator.

I launched Windows Explorer using "Run as administrator" and navigated to the folder. As far as Windows Explorer was concerned, the files didn't exist. (Note: "Show hidden files and folders" was AFAICT enabled for both me as ordinary user and for administrator.) I tried using Notepad (again as administrator; administrator-Notepad's File|Open dialog couldn't see the files either) to create a new file and save it over one of the files I couldn't see, and this appeared to succeed but did not change the file. (It did, however, change the modification date of the directory.)

Finally, as myself, I moved the files to the desktop, and then dragged them into the admin Explorer window, at which point they became visible and I was able to change the ownership from myself to administrator. They seem to have stayed visible since.

But what the @$#! is going on? I assume Windows 7 is doing something terribly clever and helpful, but I have no idea what it is.

(FWIW, my original edits were done with XEmacs under cygwin, and the problem, as best I can make out, was a straightforward one of the wrong type of line ending. But with Explorer behaving this way, I can't be sure.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the answer is [here](https://superuser.com/a/384116/100451):

> Due to security features introduced with Windows Vista (UAC) any non-Administrator program that tries to write to protected locations such as "Program Files" will get their writes caught and redirected to an alternative "user friendly" location.
>
> The program that made the file will be able to see the file, but most other programs will not.

Files written to "protected locations" will end up in a parallel file structure under `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore`, but will appear to the program that created them as if actually in the intended location.